# Can you have an event hub in a virtual network DMZ?

Tags: azure, events, firewall, azure-virtual-network

Is it possible to have a public facing event hub protected by a DMZ?

I know about IP whitelists but not sure how secure this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible. Generally, you can use the following [security features with Azure Event Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/network-security):

- Service tags
- IP Firewall rules
- Network service endpoints
- Private endpoints

For example, you can use service tags to define network access controls on [network security groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/network-security-groups-overview#security-rules) or [Azure Firewall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/service-tags). Or you can [bind event hubs to virtual networks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/network-security#bind-event-hubs-to-virtual-networks), then locked down the traffic from that VNet to access your Azure event hub. In the following diagram, you can assume that replacing the Azure DB subnet with Azure event hub subnet. You could read [this blog](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2014/11/07/secure-azure-virtual-network-and-create-dmz-on-azure-vnet-using-network-security-groups-nsg) - Secure Azure Virtual Network and create DMZ on Azure VNET using Network Security Groups (NSG) for more details.

[image]

Comment: How do you publish the Event Hub publicly though using this DMZ within a VNET? I need to publish the queue alias to a producer client on the public internet.

Comment: Do you just want to restrict the incoming traffic to your event hub via DMZ but outbound traffic to the Internet? If so, you can add [Allow access to Azure Event Hubs namespaces from specific virtual networks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-service-endpoints), then Allow Internet ingress and egress on DMZ, Allow DMZ – Hub ingress but deny internet ingress, the default Hub outbound to Internet is allowed in the subnet NSG.

Comment: How does the DNS work for the published queue though?

Comment: I think you can use the default Azure provided DNS as usual.

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered now with Azure Private Link.